# Pentaho - How do I populate an entire column with one value from another?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've been using Pentaho for a little while now, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this issue.

I want to create a new column that is populated with one value of another column.
The input source is a file with a similar structure to image below.

[[Source input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrE65.png)]

With that input; I want to create a new column that only consists of the one of the rates from another column.

[[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKtNU.png)]

I’ve tried using a UDJE step, but I can’t figure out how to extract the single value, only.

Thank you

Comment: You want only the Highest Value from 'Exchange Rate' column is that correct ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I want the Exchange rate that is associated to the Currency code - in this example GBP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have two inputs, and need to add a column from one of the sources.

PDI works with flows of data, look them like "in memory tables". Each step, generates a flow of data, after processing it.

If you have a step that needs one more column from other source, then my friend, you need to join this column, so you can use the merge join (need sorted input) step between two different sources, or stream lookup (doesn't need sorted input), so, based on keys you can get the columns you need to add from a different source.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the following solutions:

#### Solution 1

- Split your flow in two don't forget to include the keys for a later merge
- process one flow in order to get the calculation you need, in this case,  GBP_CCY_Rate.
- put it back in the main flow, using the "Lookup field" step

#### Solution 2

- Split your flow in two

In second flow:

- filter rows based on the setting you need (Filter Rows step)
- Set Variable with the result

In main flow:

- rearrange your flow so you're sure it waits until the variable has been set (maybe leave the transformation to go to your main job and then launch a second transformation here)
- use the get variable step to create the new field for your value